# How can I run multiple sequential statements in Java call to Oracle DB?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I am trying to drop a table, create it, then populate it in a single Java Statement call to Oracle DB.

I tried separating the statements with "/" on a new line in between the calls.   This WORKS in SQL Developer, but running it in through Java gives me an error.

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE FOO';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
IF sqlcode != -0942 THEN RAISE; 
END IF;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE FOO ( 
  PREFIX_SIZE number(2) NOT NULL,
  MASK number(10) NOT NULL  );
/  

BEGIN
FOR i IN 0..32 LOOP
    INSERT INTO FOO
    SELECT i, i*640 FROM DUAL;
END LOOP;
END;
```

This works in SQL Developer, but running it through Java gives the error:

ORA-06550: line 1, column 126:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"

The Java code:

```
try { 
    query = null; 
    loadSqlScript("create_table_foo.sql"); 
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);    
    preparedStatement.execute(); } 
catch......
```

The loadSqlScript just assigns the forementioned code to the query string.

Comment: Might help to post the Java code?  If you are putting these in a String in Java you might need `//` for each `/`

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add the java code, rather than posting it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Run the statements one at a time.

Since you seem to be reading the entire script from a text file, split the string on lines with nothing but a `/`, then execute each segment.

```
String fullSql = loadSqlScript("create_table_foo.sql"); 

conn.setAutoCommit(false);
try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
    for (String sql : fullSql.split("(?m)^/\\s*\\R")) {
        stmt.execute(sql);
    }
}
conn.commit();
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wound up doing; I put a specific break identifier between the statements in the SQL file and split on that and ran it as in your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the three statements into one PL/SQL block, which will only require a single call.  The code is a bit trickier than the original, because it requires dynamic SQL to run DDL and to insert into a table that doesn't exist at compile time.  But it will save some Java code and possibly improve performance by reducing network overhead.

```
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE FOO';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
  IF sqlcode != -0942 THEN RAISE; 
  END IF;
  END;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
    CREATE TABLE FOO ( 
    PREFIX_SIZE number(2) NOT NULL,
    MASK number(10) NOT NULL  )';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 0..32 LOOP
          INSERT INTO FOO
          SELECT i, i*640 FROM DUAL;
      END LOOP;
    END;';
END;
/
```